# Which tests are run after hitting 'mvn test'?

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, pom.xml

Maven project has following folder structure:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

If we navigate to maven project folder and then hit `mvn clean test`. This command will clean the project then build the project and **run the tests**

But, I didn't understand which tests it will run.

1. In which folder, of above folder structure, it will look for tests to execute? (Maybe `src/test/java`?)
2. Based on what, it will determine if particular method is test? (Maybe TestNG or JUnit test methods?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven uses [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html) test plugin by default.

It looks for the unit tests in `src/test/java` as you correctly guessed in your question.

Surefire supports several unit testing frameworks, such as JUnit and TestNG or [POJO tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/pojo-test.html). So if you have both TestNG and JUnit tests in `src/test/java` and have appropriate test dependencies for both frameworks in your pom.xml both JUnit and TestNG tests will be executed.